# WCF removing spaces from soap message

Tags: c#, wcf, c#-4.0, deserialization

We hit a bug in WCF where it is removing spaces from soap message.

so elements like the follwing

```
<desc> programming</desc>
```

when wcf converts the messages it becomes "programming".

Workaround by manipulating the message before wcf takes over.

```
  public void AfterReceiveReply(ref Message reply, object
         correlationState)
  {
       reply = TransformMessage(reply);    
  }

  private Message TransformMessage(Message oldMessage)
  {
      //load message in xmldocument, set preservewhitespace to true, save xml   
      //document and return back result.    
   }
```

However, I am concerned about the performance implications of the solution. Is there any other way to resolve this? For example instruct the deserializer which wcf uses to honor spaces?